# Capturing HTTP Requests and rewrite post Request

Tags: android, http, remote-debugging, http-toolkit

I use

1. android emulator (memu).
2. Drony - to install proxy for applications. (works socks5)

I need to change post request from application to server.

I am currently looking at traffic using the http toolkit. But this tool is inconvenient for me because there are many emulators

What I would like.

1. View traffic in real time http: port
2. Send a modified post request from the application to the server

Is it real or not?

[scheme here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSkVd.png)

Comment: Instead using drony you should try different app which provides features to modify http request by replacing request method (GET/POST), adding custom http headers etc.  To capture packet you may check tcpdump https://www.androidtcpdump.com/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this tool is inconvenient for me because there are many emulators"?

Comment: I have a lot of emulators each with specific applications installed that use proxy 
through Drony. For simplicity, I want to change post requests.
Ideal when I can parse traffic in real time through the browser line. http: port.
Then change the traffic from the application to the server.
This is in theory. But in practice, I don't know which way to move.